# When the object of the class be allocated?

Tags: c++, memory

I still feel confusion about the class, in C++ the class is a user defined type.
I think before it is instantiated, OS will do nothing for it. For one object of class, it will be allocated at running time.
If so, what will be done at compile time? In compile time, the OS picking one of the same name function based it's argument, decide the size of the member variable as well as the size of member function.

Similarly to one function, will it be loaded to CPU at compile time or running time? I guess as each function it will be attached one stack, so the function will be loaded at runtime. I hope someone could help me to correct my misunderstanding.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

All class instances are allocated at runtime of the program (unless it's stuff placed in ROM). The question isn't so much when, but where in RAM/ROM available for your processor(s) these are allocated and, if this involves an OS at all.

In general there are these different types of memory that are used to hold classes

- Stack allocated memory
- Heap allocated memory
- Global static memory
- Global static read only memory (for constant values)

The task of the compilation and linking process is to place and calculate the memory adresses correctly, that these can be used in the functions operating on them.

The only task where an OS needs to be involved might be the heap memory allocation, but there are even options to roll your own heap memory management on a bare metal system.

Answer (score 0):

The operating system has no knowledge of your class, ever.

At compile time, the compiler will define the memory structure for you class.
At link time, the linker will define the memory layout of your application, including our classes.
At run time, the OS will load your executable in memory, but it still has no knowledge of classes.

Comment: According to your explanation. I get to following conclusion. The memory allocation for the class as well as the program happens until running time. Namely, as the program is consists of several threads, thus the threads will be allocated one by one when running to them at executing time. Also, at link time, the CPU will responsible for ordering the functions of my program. Hope you could correct my fault again, thanks so much.

Comment: Your question did not mention threads, and user3500089 did not mention threads. A program consists of only one thread unless you create extra threads in the program code.